# Data is not inserted MSSQL Python

Tags: python, sql, reporting-services, pyodbc

I am doing a python script to add text files into an MSSQL table. Using pyodbc, I'm doing it. The data is not inserted in the result. There is no error showing when running.

Here is my code,

```
import pyodbc
import os
from pathlib import Path
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=LAPTOP-LMBL29RS;DATABASE=mydb;UID=sa;PWD=123456')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
path = 'testfiles'
files = os.listdir(path)
for f in files:
    filepath = path +'/'+ f
    filename = os.path.basename(path+'/'+filepath)
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        lines = fp.read().splitlines()
    with open(filepath, "r") as fp:
        count = 0;
        for line in lines:
            dataarr=[]
            if (count>0):
                dataarr = line.split(',')
                if(len(dataarr)==8):
                    print(dataarr[3])
                    query = ('INSERT INTO final_tbl("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","OpenInt","filename") '
                         'VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)')
                    cursor.execute(query, dataarr[0],dataarr[1],dataarr[2], dataarr[3], dataarr[4], dataarr[5],dataarr[6],dataarr[7])
            count = count+1
            #print(dataarr)
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `commit`?

Comment: I think I don't. There are 8 columns used in the query which is same as no of commits used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to `cnxn.commit()` after the loops are done.